# MODIS DAAC2Disk fails with "Unable to obtain ECHO token"

Tags: modis, ndvi

I have been using the tool DAAC2Disk to easily download NDVI using an extent. However recently the tool fails with the error: "Unable to obtain ECHO token"

Has anyone encountered such error? Or know where to ask about it?

Comment: I also have this problem. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Nop. I emailed MODIS and they told me that they regret the problem but such tool hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: Try this: https://git.earthdata.nasa.gov/projects/LPDUR/repos/daac_data_download_python/browse